# understanding a tuple calculation

Tags: python, tuples

I'm a Python beginner and currently working with it. For the most part I understand `tuples` but one thing has me confused. The examples I am following, is

```
print 'Number of animals in the new zoo is', \
    len(new_zoo)-1+len(new_zoo[2])
```

I understand I have a `tuple` within a `tuple` but I don't understand why I need to use -1, I have gotten rid of the -1 and tried to specify different parameters for the first instance of new_zoo, run the script and got incorrect answers or errors.

Could someone please explain why this and if there is a better way of getting the correct answer?

Comment: Without knowing what `new_zoo` is or what it contains we can't have any idea why you would need to subtract 1.

Comment: tnx for your reply i see that now and i will try to be clearer in future !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether or not to use `-1` depends entirely on what the tuple *models*.

If the tuple contains N elements but N - 1 elements are animals and the one extra element is another tuple of animals, you don't want to count that nested tuple as an animal itself, so you subtract one.

So the tuple `('zebra', 'monkey', ('lion', 'tiger', 'puma'), 'giraffe')` contains 6 animals, not 4 or 7 (the length of the outer tuple or the length of the outer tuple plus the tuple at index 2):

```
>>> new_zoo = ('zebra', 'monkey', ('lion', 'tiger', 'puma'), 'giraffe')
>>> len(new_zoo)
4
>>> len(new_zoo[2])
3
>>> len(new_zoo) + len(new_zoo[2])
7
>>> len(new_zoo) - 1 + len(new_zoo[2])
6
```

This calculation required knowing what is in the tuple, and cannot be generalised to all tuples in Python.

Comment: @YK2: so you have a tuple with 3 elements, two animals and another tuple. `len(new_zoo)` includes that nested tuple, if you don't want to count that as an animal you need to subtract 1 from the length.

Comment: i think i understand what you are trying to say, my list contains (monkey,camel(python,elephant,penguin) monkey=0,camel=1,python,elephant,penguin=2 in order to read the first tuple which ends at camel=1 we use the -1 because we are adding python,elephant,penguin=2 which is another tuple in its own right ? have i understood you correctly ?

Comment: Very grateful for your help, such a simple thing i see now, was really puzzling me !!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, backslash specified in the book is unnecessary on Python 3.4 if you have not noticed it yet.
`len(new_zoo) = 3` (monkey, camel and zoo are 3 items) - 1 give us 2 which is the number of animals in the new_zoo tuple.
`len(new_zoo[2]) = 3` because the third item in the tuple is zoo which contains 3 animals (python, elephant and penguin).
The third item in the new_zoo tuple is a nested tuple hence:

```
len(new_zoo)-1+len(new_zoo[2]) = 2 + 3 = 5
```

That's why you need to subtract 1.